# ASP.NET MVC Passing Data from View to Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view with a grid that contains items added to a workstation. The user can select an item from a drop down list and click an action link which calls a controller that adds that item to the workstation. I can make it work by reading the FormCollection object in the Post action of the controller.

```
<p>
    <% using(Html.BeginForm("AddItem", "Home")) { %>
    <label for="ItemID">Item:</label>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("ItemID", Model.ItemsList) %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("WorkstationID", Model.Workstation.RecordID) %>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <% } %>
</p>
```

---

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddItem(FormCollection formValue)
{
    long workstationId = Convert.ToInt64(formValue["WorkstationID"]);
    long itemId = Convert.ToInt64(formValue["ItemID"]);

    Workstation workstation = itilRepository.FindWorkstation(workstationId);
    Item item = itilRepository.FindItem(itemId);

    itilRepository.AddItem(workstation, item);
    itilRepository.Save();

    return Content("Item added successfully!");
}
```

What I want to do is be able to submit the two parameters the workstationId and itemId to the controller using Ajax.ActionLink and have the new item that was added get inserted into the grid. I am rendering the grid like this:

```
<table>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
      <th>
        Name
      </th>
      <th>
        Service Tag
      </th>
      <th>
        Serial Number
      </th>
    </tr>

    <% foreach (var item in Model.Items) { %>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Edit", "ItemEdit", new { id = item.RecordID }) %> |
        <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "ItemDetails", new { id = item.RecordID   })%>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.Name) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.ServiceTag) %>
      </td>
      <td>
        <%= Html.Encode(item.SerialNumber) %>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <% } %>

</table>
```

The problem I have is when I submit using the ActionLink I can't figure out how to pass in the parameters to the controller and how to update the grid without reloading the entire view.

I would really appreciate some help with this or even a link to a tutorials that does something similar.

Thank You!

This is the working version, the one problem is that when the controller returns the partial view that is all that gets rendred the actual page is gone.

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddItem", null, 
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            UpdateTargetId = "ResultsGoHere",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
        }, 
        new { @id = "itemForm" } ))
{ %>

    <label for="ItemID">Item:</label>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("itemId", Model.ItemsList) %>
    <%= Html.Hidden("workstationId", Model.Workstation.RecordID) %>

    <a href="#" onclick="$('#itemForm').submit();">Submit</a>

    <div id="ResultsGoHere">
        <% Html.RenderPartial("WorkstationItems", Model.Items); %>
    </div>

<% } %>
```

Not sure what the cause is, the replace was working correctly before but the controller wasn't getting the drop down value. Now the controller is getting the value but the partial view that is returned replaces the entire page.

The Action Method:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult AddItem(string workstationId, string itemId)
{
    long lworkstationId = Convert.ToInt64(workstationId);
    long litemId = Convert.ToInt64(itemId);

    Workstation workstation = itilRepository.FindWorkstation(lworkstationId);
    Item item = itilRepository.FindItem(litemId);

    IQueryable<Item> items = itilRepository.AddItem(workstation, item);
    itilRepository.Save();

    return PartialView("WorkstationItems", items);
}
```

This is the HTML for the View that does all the work:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ITILDatabase.Models.WorkstationFormViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Workstation Details
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="/../Content/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/../Content/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/../Content/js/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js"></script>

    <h2>
        Workstation Details</h2>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Fields</legend>
        <p>
            Record ID:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Workstation.RecordID) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            Name:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Workstation.Name) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            Description:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Workstation.Description) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            Site:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Workstation.Site.Name) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            Modified By:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Workstation.ModifiedBy) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            Modified On:
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", Model.Workstation.ModifiedOn)) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            Created By:
            <%= Html.Encode(Model.Workstation.CreatedBy) %>
        </p>
        <p>
            Created On:
            <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:g}", Model.Workstation.CreatedOn)) %>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>People</legend>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("WorkstationPeople", Model.People); %>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Positions</legend>
        <% Html.RenderPartial("WorkstationPositions", Model.Positions); %>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Items</legend>

            <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddItem", "Home", null, 
                    new AjaxOptions
                    {
                        UpdateTargetId = "ResultsGoHere",
                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
                    }, 
                    new { @id = "itemForm" } ))
            { %>

                <label for="ItemID">Item:</label>
                <%= Html.DropDownList("itemId", Model.ItemsList) %>
                <%= Html.Hidden("workstationId", Model.Workstation.RecordID) %>

                <a href="#" onclick="$('#itemForm').submit();">Submit</a>

                <div id="ResultsGoHere">
                    <% Html.RenderPartial("WorkstationItems", Model.Items); %>
                </div>

            <% } %>
    </fieldset>
    <br />
    <p>
        <%=Html.ActionLink("Edit", "WorkstationEdit", new { id = Model.Workstation.RecordID }) %>
        |
        <%=Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </p>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What result are you expecting from the AJAX call?

You could use the `AjaxHelper` object's helper methods instead of the `HtmlHelper` to render the link. For example, to get new content with an AJAX HttpPOST call and insert it into a `<div>` with the id set to `ResultsGoHere` you render the following link:

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Edit", "ItemEdit", 
                         new {
                             itemId = item.RecordId, 
                             workstationId = myWorkStationId
                         },
                         new AjaxOptions {
                             HttpMethod="POST",
                             UpdateTargetId="ResultsGoHere",
                             InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace 
                         }) %>
```

In your `AcionMethod`, you can simply test on `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` to decide what to return:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult ItemEdit(string itemId, string workstationId) {
    // edit the item and get it back

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest()) {
        return PartialView("SingleItem", item);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("ItemEdit", new { itemId = item.RecordId, workstationId = workstationId });
}

// fallback for get requests
public ActionResult ItemEdit(string itemId, string workstationId)
{
    // do stuff and return view
}
```

Comment: This is great! I still have one problem, how do I pass two Id's to the controller? I need to pass in workstationId and itemId. How do I pull out the itemId that was selected in the drop down and use it in the Action Link?

Comment: You can just add an input parameter to the actionmethod, and add it to the route values. If you want to get a nice url for the call, you'll need to add a corresponding route. I've edited my code accordingly.

Comment: One last question, how do I get the drop down list selected value inside the Ajax.ActionLink?

Comment: Actually, it might be easier to do this by using the Ajax.BeginForm() method to create a small html form element which you post with an ajax request. I'll write an alternative answer in another post, and you can choose whichever suits you the best as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you could do it using the `Ajax.BeginForm()` method instead:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("ItemEdit", null, new AjaxOptions
            {
                UpdateTargetId = "ResultsGoHere",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
            }, new { @id = "itemForm" } )
{ %>
<p>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("itemId") %></p>
<p>
    <%= Html.DropDownList("workstationId") %></p>
<p>
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#itemForm').submit();">Submit</a>
</p>
<% } %>
```

Please note that the code is in its current state in no way fully functional - the dropdownlists don't get their items from anywhere, there is no `<div>` to take care of the results from the AJAX request, and the `onclick` attribute on the link that submits the form requires that jQuery is included (in which case it is way better to give the link an id and add a `click()` event handler to it from a separate `js` file...)

EDIT: Oh, and I haven't verified that it is OK to pass a `null` value to the `routeValues` parameter. If not, just supply the controller and action names, and you'll be fine.

Comment: What does your rendered HTML look like? And your ActionMethod?

Comment: The HTML is just the code from partial view. Also the url was /Home/WorkstationDetail/1 and after the post is /Home/AddItem

Comment: I meant the HTML *before* you do the POST - that is, how the entire form etc renders on your machine.

Comment: I have added the source for the View. Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: I fixed it, if I use the regular input button it works fine. It must have something to do with the java script.

Answer (score 0):

how can you pass the model from the view to the post create action of the controller using ajax.actionlink?

Answer (score 0):

Here, as of my knowledge, we can pass data from View to Controller in two ways...

1. Using `Formcollection` built in keyword like this..

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public string filter(FormCollection fc)
   {
       return "welcome to filtering : "+fc[0];
                       (or)
       return "welcome to filtering : "+fc["here id of the control in view"];

   }
   ```

`FormCollection` will work only when you click any button inside a form. In other cases it contains only empty data

1. Using model class

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public string filter(classname cn)
   {
       return "welcome to filtering : "+cn.Empid+""+cn.Empname;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you will be able to send multiple parameters through actionLink.
For this situation please refer to the code below:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "Action Name", null, routeValues: new { pram_serviceLine = Model.ServiceLine_ID, pram_Month = Model.Month, pram_Year = Model.Year, flag = "ROTATION" }
```

Reply if it works.