# How to pass input data from the view to the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, devexpress

Im new to ASP.net MVC and I use the DevExpress-MVC extensions to build a small application, a time registration for employees, that uses a DataGrid.

My Problem is the following one:

The user is able to enter a abbreviation of his name, submitting this to the controller should call a query to my DB and show his responding Employee-ID.

I got my DataViewModel to pass my Model to the view, now I thought binding it to the textbox and retrieving the data back from the ViewModel would do it, but it does not.

My Code looks like that:
 **ViewModel**

```
    public class MyErfassungViewModel
{
    public MyErfassung erfassung;
    public String personalnummer;
    public String personalkuerzel;
    public List<String> dim1;
    public List<String> dim2;
    public List<String> dim3;
    public List<String> dim4;
    public List<String> dim5;

    public MyErfassungViewModel(MyErfassung myerfassung)
    {
        this.erfassung = myerfassung;
    }
}
```

**View**

```
    @model DevExpressMvcApplication.Models.ViewModel.MyErfassungViewModel
    <div class ="Personalnummer">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("getNummer","MyErfassung"))
    {
        <label>Personalkürzel</label>
        @Html.DevExpress().TextBox(settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "TextBoxPersonalkürzel";
        }).Bind(Model.personalkuerzel).GetHtml()

        <label>Personalnummer</label>

        @Html.DevExpress().TextBox(settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "TextBoxPersonalnummer";
            settings.ReadOnly = true;
        }).Bind(Model.personalnummer).GetHtml()

        @Html.DevExpress().Button(settings =>
        {
            settings.Name = "TextBoxKuerzel";
            settings.Text = "Holen";
            settings.UseSubmitBehavior = true;
        }).GetHtml()
        <br>
    }
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
    //
    // GET: /MyErfassung/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        viewModel.personalkuerzel = "sese";
        return View(viewModel);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getNummer()
    {
        String kurz = Convert.ToString(Request["TextBoxKuerzel"]);
        String nr = Convert.ToString(Request["TextBoxPersonalnummer"]);

        String nummer = dbRepo.getPersonalnummerByKuerzel(viewModel.personalkuerzel);
        viewModel.personalnummer = nummer;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Like you are able to see I tried some possible ways to receive the user input and send a DB-Request to get a number.
But either the request or the viewmodel are containing more than a null reference.

But simply said I am not able to pass users input from my form back to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to pass the view model to your controller action and the model binder will take care of the rest. You can then access these properties and do with them as you see fit:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult getNummer(MyErfassungViewModel viewModel)
{
    String nummer = dbRepo.getPersonalnummerByKuerzel(viewModel.personalkuerzel);
    ...
}
```

When you define a `MyErfassungViewModel` parameter (called, for example, `viewModel`) to your POST action method, the ASP.NET MVC model binder will take the form values that come from your view, populate an instance of `MyErfassingViewModel` and pass that into your method.

At the moment, the parameter list of your `getNummer` method is empty, so there is nowhere to pass in the view model.

Update: Because `MyErfassungViewModel` has an overloaded constructor, you'll need to add a default constructor so the model binder can instantiate it:

```
public class MyErfassungViewModel
{
    public MyErfassung erfassung;
    public String personalnummer;
    public String personalkuerzel;
    public List<String> dim1;
    public List<String> dim2;
    public List<String> dim3;
    public List<String> dim4;
    public List<String> dim5;

    public MyErfassungViewModel(MyErfassung myerfassung)
    {
        this.erfassung = myerfassung;
    }

    public MyErfassungViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds wonderful, but if I try this I get "No parameterless constructor defined for this object."  I tried to understand how the scaffold templates are realizing that, but the connection from the view to the controller is still some kind of magic to me.  I think that Im missing something in Line 3 of my View: "@using (Html.BeginForm("getNummer","MyErfassung"))"

Comment: Can you post the whole stack trace?

Comment: This solved the exception, but unfortunately the object of MyErfassung that he is getting does not contain the form data, myerfassung.personalkuerzel is null, so the input was not passed to it.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with DevExpress but it looks like you're overriding the `name` of the textbox: `settings.Name = "TextBoxPersonalkürzel";` - This will change the name of the post value and make it impossible to match the field to the model's property. Try removing that line? You'd also have to do this with the other inputs.

Comment: I had this intention too, but removing the name led to a exception and naming the extensions like the model attributes did not change anything. I will try this with a usual textbox, I like your solution much more than the one I posted, so I will investigate that further. Thank you for the effort.

Comment: The reason why all this did not work is in the MyErfassungViewModel, I did not set the {get;set;} properties.

Comment: @PreDer D'oh! Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that finally lead me to my data is presented in the following question

[ASP.NET MVC Passing Data from View to Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013468/asp-net-mvc-passing-data-from-view-to-controller?rq=1)

For my solutions the code looks like that:
**View**

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult getNummer()
    {
        String kurz = Convert.ToString(Request["personalkuerzel"]);
        String nr = Convert.ToString(Request["personalnummer"]);

        String nummer = dbRepo.getPersonalnummerByKuerzel(kurz);
        viewModel.personalnummer = nummer;
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Unfortunately it seems like this solution does not use the comfortable way that Ant P has described, of automatically applying response data to the model.

Comment: [link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx) The above solution is not the way you should do that, visit the link to see how to bind properly.